# Hiding a fixed CSS menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's my first time building a website and I've found myself stuck with something that may just be a misunderstanding of some fundamental html markup principles, so please go easy.

I have a fixed CSS menu that sits at the top of the screen like this:

```
<div class="banner-contain" id="myTopNav">
    <div class="cssmenu w3-container">
        <div class="w3-col s4 w3-left"><span class="w3-opennav w3-hide-large w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey" onclick="w3_open()"><i class="fa fa-bars"> .  </i></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 .cssmenu {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.94);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #999;
}
```

I can successfully hide it with the following JS:

```
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myTopNav").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("hide-pad").style.display = "none";
}

function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myTopNav").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("hide-pad").style.display = "block";
}
```

Hide pad simply toggles the removal of padding I use to keep my page content below the menu.

Now the actual issue; I want to modify my CSS menu to look more like this, but the function no longer works as intended (i.e. doesn't hide the complete contents of the ID myTopNav):

```
<div class="banner-contain" id="myTopNav">    
    <div class="cssmenu w3-container">
        <div class="w3-row">
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-left"><span class="w3-opennav w3-hide-large w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey" onclick="w3_open()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span></div>
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center"><h3 class="w3-wide logo"><b>HELP</b></h3></div>
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center"><p>s4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your advice in advance, and from all the advice taken previously as a lurker -sgn

Comment: You have to change the Id of either Parent div or child div from "myTopNav", because two element with same Id creating the issue here.

Comment: You have used same ID twice. ID must be unique

Comment: I just made an edit to remove the ID from `"<div class="cssmenu w3-container" id="myTopNav">"` reflecting the code I actually originally meant to submit, that code doesn't work. I also tried the other possibility of creating two separate IDs of different names, along the lines of what you were suggesting (myTopNav myTopNav2) but had no luck with it either.

Answer (score 1):

Remove onClick function from current div and give to the parent div.

so your code looks something like this now.

```
<div class="banner-contain" id="myTopNav" onclick="w3_open()">    
    <div class="cssmenu w3-container">
       <div class="w3-row">
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-left"><span class="w3-opennav w3-hide-large w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span></div>
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center"><h3 class="w3-wide logo"><b>HELP</b></h3></div>
          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center"><p>s4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope it works !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's replies, it turns out I made a rookie error and got myself confused with a css viewport (?) setting, I needed `@media (min-width:993px)banner-contain{display:none!important}` in order to have the banner hidden, and then it could be toggled to view on either the top or left - this solved my problem but I really wasn't asking the right question, sorry about that.